# How to make div responsive with assigned height

Tags: css

user have ability to set height of some div in "px". And if he do that, than some div have height like this:

```
height: 245px;
```

but if this is done, then height stays the same which is not good for responsive design. Because i want that that div needs to adjusts to the conditions of responsive design.

So my question is what could I do in css to make div responsive ?

that later the height of div adjusts to the conditions of responsive design.

therefore, the height of div does not need to be fixed.

I have also tried this:

```
height: 100vw;
max-height: 245px;
```

but this also not works, as div stays at height of 245px.

Thank you

Comment: Don't set any height.

Comment: this is not an option...

Comment: Your requirements are in conflict. You want to both fix the height and not fix the height? Perhaps `min-height` is what you're looking for?

Comment: No, i want to have ability to set height for div, but at the same time if user opens website with lover resoluton then div needs to adjusts to the conditions, and then div height does not need to be same.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `PX`to `%`, so it will be responsive.

use the formula:

```
size-in-pixel/Screen-Size*100 = it gives the percentage
```

in your code in place of the size in pixel enter the value in percentage